# Insert a note in a Google Sheet with google-sheets-api

Tags: rest, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm looking at the following documentation for Google Sheets and I'm wondering how do I add/update a cell with a Note attached to it.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}
```

I can't seem to find a sample request body of what it looks like to add a note. I've tried to send a PUT request but of course it returned a 400.

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      {
        "note": "sample note"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid values[17][0]: struct_value {\n  fields {\n    key: \"note\"\n    value {\n      string_value: \"sample note\"\n    }\n  }\n}\n",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564368/insert-a-comment-in-a-google-sheet-with-google-sheets-api

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti that doesn't work