# programatically create a comment and assign it to someone in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, comments, google-sheets-api

It's been a while since similar questions were asked so I thought I would try again. And, none of the existing questions speak to assigning the comment/task -- just to creating a comment.

Is it possible to programatically create a comment in a Google Sheet and assign it to someone. You can do this through the UI when you manually create a comment. If you enter an email address you can assign the comment (as a task) to them.

I know it is possible to use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/insert to create a comment but the comment is created on the whole file, not a specific cell. And, even still, I can't find how to assign the comment.

Comment: If something new is announced by Google, usually those similar questions will be answered by one of us.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517097/ (Even inserting is currently not possible. Assigning would be a step above that)

Comment: Yeah, "assignment" is not exposed in any way by the API (neither v2 you refer to, nor v3). Sheets use an undocumented `anchor` type `workbook-range` - you can try to hack around, but that would be very unreliable as I am sure you know (and that assumes you can figure out the logic behind the `range` parameter)

Comment: I was able to anchor a comment to a cell so it shows the little orange arrow in the cell but it doesn't show the comment when you hover over the cell. I submitted a feature request so hoping they implement. http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160685101

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - may I ask you how you managed to even anchor it to the cell via the API? Thank you for the feature request, btw

Comment: @OlegValter I used this for the `anchor` attribute: `{"r":"head","a":[{"matrix":{"r":2,"c":2}}],"type":"workbook-range","uid":0,"range":"1493575397"}`. It shows the orange triangle but wont show the comment when you hover. I feel like there is some hidden secret. I'm still playing around with it.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - huh, I see, I stopped trying as soon as I got the confirmation that we have to use an undocumented anchor type for that (I thought that you managed to do that without it). Thank you for checking, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a comment it's not possible through the API. You can only create a comment with the Drive API to a specific file.

You should submit a [feature request here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/support#missing_features) if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I did end up submitting a FR: http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160685101.