# How do you programatically insert an anchored comment on a rectangular region of a PDF file on Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

So I'm trying to programmatically insert anchored comments on all the pdf files in a folder.

I read the following doc:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments#anchor
I tried following the instructions to creating an anchored comment on a rectangular region. But whenever I do, it appears as an unanchored comment only. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
function insertComment(driveAppFolderObject) {
  let files = driveAppFolderObject.getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()){
      let fileId = files.next().getId()
      let comment = {'content':'Comment Testing',
      'anchor':{
        'r': 'head',
        'a': [
          {
            'rect':
            {
              'x': 20,
              'y': 20,
              'w': 10,
              'h': 10,
            }
          }]
        }
      };
      Drive.Comments.insert(comment, fileId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive API ignores anchor parameter when creating comments in a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511838/google-drive-api-ignores-anchor-parameter-when-creating-comments-in-a-spreadshee)

Comment: Not really. I am not trying to comment on a spreadsheet, I am trying to comment on a pdf. And I'm not sure what "you need to create your own app to process those comments" means or if it would be helpful for my situation.

Comment: Try get comment that you added and you will see

Comment: By the way, Apps Script `Drive` uses API `v2`, and documentation link you posted is `v3`

Comment: Thanks, but the v2 says the same thing:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-comments

Comment: Wait, nevermind, I get it. v2 does not have anchor as an optional parameter, v3 does. Sorry if I sound totall inexperienced, but how can I use v3?

Comment: > `As mentioned earlier, the JSON anchor string contains a revisionID (r) and region (a) [..]` I think it means `anchor` parameter should be a string, not object, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498275/creating-anchored-comments-programmatically-in-google-docs

Comment: I just did JSON.stringify() on the anchor parameter, and the code continued to behave in the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will using Drive v3 allow me to insert anchored comments on pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319140/will-using-drive-v3-allow-me-to-insert-anchored-comments-on-pdf-files)