How to send content as comment to a specific cell in google sheets
Using the Google Drive API and Python, I created a code that allows me to create a comment in a specific cell in Google Sheets when I type something into a form and click the submit button, but it doesn't work.
When I look at the comments tab, the comment is created, then it says [Original content deleted], and it doesn't even show that the cell is commented on.
Is there a solution? The code I created is shown below.
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

content = request.form.get('content')

comment = drive_service.comments().create(
fileId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
body={
'content': content
},
fields='id'
).execute()


Use Google Sheet API directly.
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
content = request.form.get('content')

# Define the range for the cell
range_ = 'Sheet1!A1'

comment = {
    'content': content,
    'location': {
        'sheetId': 0,
        'rowIndex': 0,
        'columnIndex': 0
    }
}

sheets_service.spreadsheets().comments().create(
    spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
    body=comment
).execute()

Google Drive API will allow you to comment on file level and not cell level

I can't find anything about comments in the Google Sheets API, is there any documentation?

You should refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564368/insert-a-comment-in-a-google-sheet-with-google-sheets-api
